# angularjs - How I can know the path of a state until another state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm too new in AngularJS and I have the following question:

How I can know the path of a state until another state?

I want to know how to show all states through which it passes up to one state in particular.

e.g : I have the following States: Home, login and menuContent. If this start on menuContent and then continues to login and ends at home, I want to see the entire route or at least before the home's state that would be the last

```
.state('home', {
     url: "/home",
      cache: false,
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: "app/pages/dashboard.html",
              controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
            },
        },
})

.state('login', {
     url: "/login",
      cache: false,
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: "app/modules/login/authentication.html",
             controller: 'AuthenticationCtrl'
            },
        },
})

.state('menuContext', {
     url: "/menuContext",
      cache: false,
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: "app/modules/login/menuContext.html",
             controller: 'menuContextCtrl'
            },
        },
})
```

I hope that point will be understood and apologize for my english

Many thanks in advance,

Regards, CMol

Comment: Can you clarify what is the use case? Why you want to see the states info? May be that would help solve the question

Comment: Hi, to do a debug , I want to know exactly through which it passes

Comment: For debugging you can easily debug from Inspect element in chrome browse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two data handling options here: either create a service or stick your data to the `$rootScope` object.

The interesting part is how you get/store your data in the service/ object:

- you can push data on `$stateChangeStart` event (like Ivan stated) and return some kind of aggregated path whenever needed
- you can use UI Routers `onEnter` property in state config to push state data like so:

.

```
$stateProvider.state('state1.substate1', {
   url: "/substate1",
   templateUrl: "templates/substate1.html",
   controller: 'substate1Ctrl',
   onEnter: function(){
       $rootScope.path += '/substate1';
   }    
});
```

See [docs on $stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) here (onEnter is listed as a function of $state).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to listen to `$stateChangeStart` event, in handler you will have fromState argument, so you can track those previous states and do whatever you want. You could also make some service and pass there these previous states and it will build/store full path for you.

Check out [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of objects with all rules. And then, you can register with a loop. And then, you can to access this object to generate your list.

An example code:

```
var rules = {
    'home': { url: "/home", cache: false, ... },
    'login': { url: "/login", cache: false, ... }
}

angular.forEach(rules, function(value, key) {
    $routeProvider.state(key, value);
});
```